# CouchDb automatic timestamps

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I'm implementing a message application using CouchDB.  I want to apply timestamps to each message.  I found some references indicating that I should use [document update handlers](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers) for this.  In place updates seem like the right thing.  But where would I get a timestamp from?  Is it in the req object somewhere?

```
{
  updates: {
    "in-place" : function(doc, req) {
      doc.timestamp = "???";
      var message = "set timestamp to "+doc.timestamp;
      return [doc, message];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812235/whats-the-best-way-to-store-datetimes-timestamps-in-couchdb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to use javascript's date functions.

```
{
  updates: {
    "in-place" : function(doc, req) {
      doc.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
      var message = "set timestamp to "+doc.timestamp;
      return [doc, message];
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, getting this update to trigger from jcouchdb is the next problem.

Comment: what do you mean "getting this update to trigger is the next problem": do you mean once the update-handler written, the problem is how to trigger it "automatically" as soon as the document is updated?